# Node-RED WebSocket Request-Response Node

Tags: websocket, node-red

Using `Node-RED 1.2.9`

1. Is it possible to get the `WebSocket` instance created by the built in `websocket in` node downstream?  I think I need it for what I want to do in question #2.
2. We have a request-response JSON protocol using web sockets.

   It would be awesome if there was a node for web sockets that behaved
   just like the `http request` node (it sends a request, waits for a
   response, and then forwards it to the next node).

   I'm new to Node-RED; how could I do that?

[image]

**NOTE:**
If you are wondering why we don't just use HTTP/REST its because security requirements for our product dictate that communication is initiated in only one direction.
We have to behave like `"don't call us we'll call you"`.
Making Node-RED do HTTP requests back to our service is not allowed (hence the websocket incoming to Node-RED).

Comment: Node-RED 1.2.9 went totally EoL in July 2022, you really should be looking to upgrade.

Comment: Okay, @hardillb.  But will upgrading solve my problem?

Comment: Probably not, but new functionality to core nodes is only ever going to be delivered on the latest version. Just to be clear, you want NR to act as a server and wait for something else to connect, then send requests from the from the server and then output the replies?

Comment: Ideally I would have a websocket node that can do exactly what "http request" does.  It receives an input, sends that as a request, then waits for a response, then forwards that to the next node. I will update my question with a picture.

Comment: But the http-request node connects out, the bit I'm trying to clarify is that you need that "request" node to act as a server that your service has to connect to first, before requests are made.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was hoping it could re-use the websocket connection established by the "websocket in" node preceeding it.

Comment: But how would the backend of the node know to route the "response" to the request node, and not the input node as there works be nothing in the ws message to distinguish from any othe message sent over the connection

Comment: Yes... I see your point @hardillb.  I suppose I would have to write my own nodes then.
The only thing I can think of is to write my own custom nodes and somehow share a websocket connection between them with some logic to determine where we are in the flow and which node is handling the next message from the websocket.